# It's possible do connect in a server using SSH through other SSH connection in Java?

Tags: java, ssh

I have two servers (Server1 and Server2),
on my network, i can connect only with ssh to Server1, my network can't see Server2...

I want to make a program that connects in Server1, and starts a new connection to Server2 using ssh again.

I have already connected to Server1 using SSH libs in java, but i don't know how to start a new connection using my actual ssh session.

It's like in terminal do a `ssh Server2@10.1.10.10`

How can i do this?

Comment: have you tried doing your_username@server2.full.qualified.domain.name from server1 ? If you just do ssh server2 from server1 you may not have access / privileges ...

Comment: You, most likely, could setup server1 as a proxy and use port forwarding.  It is relatively easy to do.  In your .ssh/config file you basically setup an alias for server2 and tell ssh to use server1 as a proxy to connect.  Check out: [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding).

Comment: Why do you want to make a program? You could just use ProxyCommand that connects to Server1 and runs netcat to make Server2 available

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that you have for connecting to server1?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with most Java SSH APIs as its simply a case of performing a port forward to the second host after connecting to the first and then connecting the input/output of a tunnel into a new client instance.

However with the [J2SSH Maverick](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick) open source API we make this quite easy and do the forwarding setup for you.

The code below demonstrates how you do this, first open a connection to the first server. Then once connected call openRemoteClient and it will return an SshClient object for the second. In the background this uses port forwarding to connect the second client.

The example uses password authentication but you could of course use any type of authentication.

```
// Create initial connection
SshConnector con = SshConnector.createInstance();
SshClient ssh = con.connect(new SocketTransport("host.external", 22), "ubuntu");

// Authenticate
PasswordAuthentication pwd = new PasswordAuthentication();
pwd.setPassword("xxxxxxx");

ssh.authenticate(pwd);

// Created forwarded connection
SshClient remoteClient = ssh.openRemoteClient("host.internal", 22, "ubuntu");

// Now you have to authenticate the second client
.....
```